# How to show not more than two rows in ionic 4

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, row, ionic4

I have a category list it displays dynamically in rows and columns.
But I want to show only two rows and it if contains more than two rows than show button View More.
The current scenario is it shows all categories. But want show only 2 rows.

How to do this.

**Response**

> [{"categoryId":"1","name":"General
>   Knowledge","image":"https://codehub.biz/knowledgeup/API/images/gk_categaries_icons.png"},{"categoryId":"3","name":"Biology","image":"https://codehub.biz/knowledgeup/API/images/biology_categaries_icons.png"},{"categoryId":"4","name":"Chemistry","image":"https://codehub.biz/knowledgeup/API/images/Chemastry_Categaries_Icons.png"},{"categoryId":"5","name":"Economy","image":"https://codehub.biz/knowledgeup/API/images/Economy.png"},{"categoryId":"6","name":"Sports","image":"https://codehub.biz/knowledgeup/API/images/sports_categaries_icons.png"},{"categoryId":"7","name":"Physics","image":"https://codehub.biz/knowledgeup/API/images/physics.png"},{"categoryId":"8","name":"World
>   Geography","image":"https://codehub.biz/knowledgeup/API/images/geo.png"},{"categoryId":"10","name":"Science
>   &
>   Inventions","image":"https://codehub.biz/knowledgeup/API/images/science.png"},{"categoryId":"11","name":"test","image":"https://codehub.biz/knowledgeup/API/images/bg.png"},{"categoryId":"12","name":"test1234","image":"https://codehub.biz/knowledgeup/API/images/2745032977bg.png"},{"categoryId":"13","name":"binjal","image":"https://codehub.biz/knowledgeup/API/images/651543756ON40S50.jpg"}]

**tab1.html**

```
<div>
    <ion-label class="label">All</ion-label>
    <ion-grid>
      <ion-row class="margin" *ngFor="let row of grid">
        <ion-col size="3" class="ion-text-center" *ngFor="let item of row"
          (click)="quizInfo(item.categoryId,item.name,item.image)">
          <img class="logo" [src]='item.image' *ngIf="item"> <br>
          <p class="margin title" *ngIf="item">{{item.name}}</p>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
  </div>
```

**tab1.ts**

```
public categoryList: any;
  grid: Array<Array<string>>;
  gridLength: any;

getCategoryData() {
    let loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
      spinner: 'circles',
      message: 'Please wait...'
    }).then(loading => loading.present());

    this.authService.getData("getcategories.php").then((result) => {
      this.categoryList = result;
      console.log(this.categoryList);

      this.grid = Array(Math.ceil(this.categoryList.length / 4)); //MATHS!
      this.gridLength = this.grid.length;
      console.log(this.gridLength);

      if(this.gridLength>2){
        this.txt = "more than 2 rows";
      } else {
        this.txt = "less than or equal to 2 rows";
      }

      console.log(this.txt);

      let rowNum = 0; //counter to iterate over the rows in the grid

      for (let i = 0; i < this.categoryList.length; i += 4) { //iterate images

        this.grid[rowNum] = Array(4); //declare two elements per row

        if (this.categoryList[i]) { //check file URI exists
          this.grid[rowNum][0] = this.categoryList[i] //insert image
        }

        if (this.categoryList[i + 1]) { //repeat for the second image
          this.grid[rowNum][1] = this.categoryList[i + 1]
        }

        if (this.categoryList[i + 2]) { //repeat for the second image
          this.grid[rowNum][2] = this.categoryList[i + 2]
        }

        if (this.categoryList[i + 3]) { //repeat for the second image
          this.grid[rowNum][3] = this.categoryList[i + 3]
        }

        rowNum++; //go on to the next row
      }

      this.loadingCtrl.dismiss();
    }, (err) => {
      this.loadingCtrl.dismiss();
      console.log("Error", err);
    });
  }
```

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can track the indes  and use it with ngIf.

```
<ion-row class="margin" *ngFor="let row of grid; let i = index;">
<ion-col *ngIf="i < 10"
.....
<span *ngIf="i === 10">Show more</span>
```

Something like this

Comment: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors: Can't have multiple template bindings on one element. Use only one attribute prefixed with * (""let row of grid ; let i = index;">
        <ion-col size="3" class="ion-text-center" *ngIf="i < 2" [ERROR ->]*ngFor="let item of row"(click)="quizInfo(item.categoryId,item.name,item.image)">
        ")

Comment: Can't use *ngIf and *ngFor together.

Comment: Wrap ngFor inside a ng-container, then you can use ngIf below it.